# Contador de visitas, en cada noticia

Tags: php, html, mysql

Buenas estoy creando un contador de visitas, así utilizarlo a modo de que página se visita más y además quiero poner en la muestra de cada noticia del blog un icono con un ojo y cuantas veces se a visto esa  noticia.

Tengo un archivo llamado **visitas.php**

```
ob_start();
header("Content-type: text/javascript");

// Creamos la conexion con la base de datos
$con = @mysqli_connect('servidor', 'usuario', 'pass', 'bd') or die("document.write('Error');");

// Obtenemos, y validamos enlace actual
$enlace = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if (!$enlace || $enlace == '') {
    die();
}

// Obtenemos los datos de la base de datos
$sql = "SELECT visitas FROM visitas WHERE enlace='$enlace'";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

/*creamos los codigos querys verificando primero las cookies, para contar visitas y no impresiones web*/
if (isset($_COOKIE[md5($enlace)])) {
    // si existe la cookie solo le damos el valor a $visitas
    $visitas = $row['visitas'];
    echo "document.write($visitas);";
} elseif (!isset($_COOKIE[md5($enlace)])) {
    // Comprobamos si el enlace ya esta en la base de datos
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if ($rows > 0) {
        // Cuando exista lo enlace actualizamos
        $SQL = "UPDATE visitas SET visitas=visitas+1 WHERE enlace='$enlace'";
        if (mysqli_query($con, $SQL)) { // Si se inserta la visita
            $visitas = ($row['visitas']) + (1); // Le sumamos uno para mostrar la visita actual
            echo "document.write($visitas);";
            setcookie(md5($enlace), '_vStD', time() + 86400); // Y creamos la cookie de 1 dia
        } else { // Si no se inserta la visita
            $visitas = $row['visitas']; // Solo obtenemos las visitas
            echo "document.write($visitas);";
        }
    } elseif ($rows == 0) {
        // Cuando no existe el enlace en la base de datos la insertamos
        $SQL = "INSERT INTO visitas (enlace,visitas) VALUES ('$enlace',1)";
        if (mysqli_query($con,$SQL)) { // Si se inserta la nueva enlace
            echo "document.write(1);";
            setcookie(md5($enlace), '_vStD', time() + 86400); // Y creamos la cookie de 1 dia
        } else { // Si no se inserta mostramos
            echo "document.write(0);";
        }
    }
}

// Por ultimo cerramos la conexion, y cerramos el script
ob_end_flush();
mysqli_close($con);
die();
```

Luego pongo este fragmento en cada página para almacenar todas ellas:

```
<script src="https://web.es/visitas.php"></script>
```

Esto me almacena los datos más o menos así:

*idvisitas:* 1 
*enlace:* https://web.es/ver-noticia.php?ID=2 
*visitas:* 1 /veces visitado/

Las noticias se ven según la ID me muestra una noticia o otra.
La cuestión no se como generar una consulta para que con los datos que guardo poner las visitas que tiene cada noticia.

Asi muestro los datos de cada una de las noticias:

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT((nt.fecha), '%d/%m/%Y')
             AS date, nt.idNoticia, nt.imagen, nt.titulo, nt.cuerpo, nt.cuerpo, nt.idUs, nt.idCategoria, nt.fecha, nt.estado, ct.idCategoria, ct.valor, us.idus, us.usuario, us.foto
             FROM noticia AS nt, categoriasBlog AS ct, usuariosBlog AS us
             WHERE nt.idCategoria = ct.idCategoria
             AND nt.idUs = us.idus AND nt.estado = 1
             ORDER BY nt.idNoticia DESC");
              foreach ($results as $noticias){
              $prueba = $noticias['idNoticia'];
```

Campos que almaceno en la bd de las noticias:

*idNoticia:* 
*imagen:* 
*titulo:* 
*subtitulo:* 
*cuerpo:* 
*idUs:* 
*idCategoria:* 
*fecha:* 
*estado:*

Alguna sugerencia? no se si me he explicado bien.

**EDITO**

He añadido un campo a la tabla de las noticias que se llama enlace y lo insertare automáticamente cuando inserte una noticia. Así de este modo puedo comparar las tablas y sacar los datos. Pero estoy realizando está consulta pero sin éxito.

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT FORMAT SUM(vi.visitas) as suma, 
vi.enlace, vi.idvisitas, no.idNoticia, no.titulo, no.enlace
    FROM visitas as vi, noticia as no
    WHERE vi.enlace = no.enlace
    GROUP BY vi.idvisitas");
    foreach ($results as $contador){
```

Comment: No entiendo porque usas el "enlace". Simplemente relaciona las visitas con el ID de la noticia, el enlace es algo "dinámico" que no debería usarse con dicha finalidad. Es más, ni siquiera te hace falta una tabla para las visitas, con un campo en la tabla de la noticia te vale. Al cargar la noticia, haces un +1 de las visitas de ese ID y listo.

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta! y como hago ese +1 en la noticia?? Por curiosidad, que esta fallando algo en la query verdad?

Comment: `UPDATE table SET column = column + 1 where idforeign = id;` cambiando table por la tabla de visitas, column por la columna contador de visitas e id por el valor de relacion con la noticia que tengas (en tu caso el enlace aunque yo lo cambiaria para guardar directamente el ID de la noticia)

Comment: Pero esto lo pongo en la pagina de ver-noticia y se insertan los valores. Pero eso no tiene ninguna cookie para duplicar viistas

Comment: Claro, ya el control de duplicados y similar lo debes controlar como veas (cookie, session...) y solo ejecutar la query cuando corresponda.

Comment: Vale parece perfecto! pero ya por curiosidad, en lo de antes que falla la query?? no me quiero quedar con la duda